# i can't use else if statement in C

Tags: c

[image]

i'm trying to make a user input that consist string(char array) datatype with if statements alongside else if and else statements. i can do it with an integer but i can't do it with char array, it only runs in if statement not in else if

i put "%s" for format specifiers and it still doesn't work

Comment: Don't post links to pictures of code.  Post the actual code.  That said, your `if` conditions make no sense.  You're using comma expressions which always evaluate to true.  You might want to consult a tutorial that shows how to use an `if` statement.

Comment: Do you have a C book? You need a C book.

Comment: See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15168) for a more detailed discussion of why images of code are bad.  Please read the [Ask] page again.

Comment: aight i appreciate it, thanks

Comment: never call your programs `test` unless you work on the `test` command source

Comment: For a future lesson, if you prompt with `"Input anything"` you should expect  to receive more than 10 characters. For example, my cat could jump on the keyboard and generate `"cqlrhcqrhlhjcqrqrhjwhjvbmnvb"`.

Comment: You seem to be using some language other than C or something you have invented.  The condition in an `if` should be a Boolean expression.  Because `,` is an operator in C, it will compile and convert the expression to Boolean where the result of the first `if` is always true.  Note also that in C there is no `else if` statement - that is merely an `else` followed by an `if` statement.  It is idiomatic layout not to indent an `if` when it immediately follows an `else`, and to place it on the same line without `{`.

Comment: Format specifiers have no syntactic meaning in C, they are used in _string_ arguments for formatted I/O functions in the standard library.  Their semantics are entirely defined by the implementation of such I/O functions and not by the C language.  If you use a literal-string constant as an operand in an expression, the operand is simply a non-null pointer, which when implicitly converted to Boolean as here, becomes `true` (because it is non-zero).  The semantics of the comma operator are such that only `"bbb"` affects the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very wrong:

```
if ("%s",karakter[10] == "%s","aaa") {
```

If you are trying to compare the contents of a char array to see if it contains a particular string, you should use the `strcmp()` function for that, like this:

```
if (strcmp(karakter, "aaa") == 0) {
```

... same thing for the `else if` clause, it should look more like this:

```
else if (strcmp(karakter, "bbb") == 0) {
```

You probably also want to put your `\n` newline characters at the *end* of the format-strings you pass to `printf()`, rather than at the beginning of the format-strings.  Note that the `\n` forces the text to get flushed to the console, so any text that you print that is not followed by a `\n` may not appear right away, unless you explicitly call `fflush(stdout);` afterwards.